# If statement with MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Trying to change this code so that I can choose which numbers(values) show which information, here is the code as it is now:

```
$sql_doublecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminpage WHERE setting='main' AND close_site='1'");
$doublecheck = mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck);

if ($doublecheck == 0) {
    echo "<strong><font color=red>> Close site is off</font></strong>";
} else if ($doublecheck > 0) {
    echo "<strong><font color=green>> Close site is working</strong></font><br />";
}
```

That all seems to work fine, however in the database "close_site" is a enum with 4 options "0, 1, 2, 3" I would like to make an if statement for each number... really simple terms:

if "0" echo "Close site is off"
if "1" echo "Maintenance mode active"
if "2" echo "Close site is on"
if "3" echo "Another option"

I know the above isn't in code but that's what I am hoping to achieve. I'm wondering if it would be something like:

```
$sql_doublecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminpage WHERE setting='main' AND close_site='1'");
$doublecheck = mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck);

if($doublecheck == 0) {
    echo "<strong><font color=red>> Close site is off</font></strong>";
} else if ($doublecheck == 1) {
    echo "<strong><font color=green>> Maintenance mode active</strong></font><br />";
} else if ($doublecheck == 2) {
    echo "<strong><font color=green>> Close site is on</strong></font><br />";
}
```

Not too sure? Thanks

Comment: I would put the descriptions and colors in a separate lookup table. Join your `adminpage` table to the lookup table on `close_site` columns, and then pull the description and color from there to draw your page. Keeps your UI code super clean and maintenance is a breeze.

Comment: Since close_site actually has a value, you really should just retrieve that value and work with it, rather than looking "if there are > 0 rows with close_site>0". Just select it, and show it. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to something like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminpage WHERE setting='main'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
switch($result['close_site']) {
   case 4:
       echo 'something to show when close_site=4';
       break;
   case 3:
       echo 'something to show when close_site=3';
       break;
   case 2:
       echo 'something to show when close_site=2';
       break;
   case 1:
      echo "<strong><font color=green> Close site is working</strong></font><br />";
      break;
   case 0:
   default:
      echo 'close site is off, or none of the above';
}
```

On a sidenote, you really should stop using the mysql extension since it's officially deprecated, and switch to either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo)

Comment: I will give this a try, and yeah I've heard a lot of people say that, only problem is my web host is still running MySQL, not sure if I can really do anything about that?

Comment: your webhost is very likely also allowing the use of the MySQLi and PDO extensions. It's not the *database server* that needs to change, but the *driver* between PHP and MySQL. So there's nothing wrong with using MySQL itself, just stop using the mysql extension in PHP. The MySQL server works just fine (even better) with both the MySQLi extension as well as the PDO extension.